# Wordpress order get_categories() list with category that has had the latest post on top

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, wp-list-categories

I wonder if someone would be kind enough to help me out.

I need to be able to display sub categories, then display the posts within that subcategory. 
I have it limited so that only 2 subcategories display and only 2 post for each display.

- Subcategory A

  - Post
  - Post
- Subcategory B

  - Post
  - Post

What I need to do is order the categories so that the category that has the LATEST post added  is on top. e.e. if another post gets added to Subcatergory B then that list appears above Subcategory A.

This is the code I have at the moment

```
$catid = 2;
$subcats = get_categories('child_of=' . $catid.'&number=2');
    foreach($subcats as $subcat) {
    echo '<li>' . $subcat->cat_name . '</li>';
    echo '<ul>';
   $subcat_posts = get_posts('cat=' . $subcat->cat_ID.'&posts_per_page=2');
foreach($subcat_posts as $subcat_post) {
        $postID = $subcat_post->ID;
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($postID) . '">';
    echo get_the_title($postID);
    echo '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    }?>
```

Any ideas would be gratefully appreciated.

M

Answer (score 0):

Add the following sorting function to your functions.php:

```
function sort_categories_by_post_date($a, $b) {
    $a_posts = get_posts('cat=' . $a->term_id);
    $b_posts = get_posts('cat=' . $b->term_id);

    if (!$a_posts) {
        $a_cmp = 0;
    } else {
        $a_cmp = strtotime($a_posts[0]->post_date);
    }

    if(!$b_posts) {
        $b_cmp = 0;
    } else {
        $b_cmp = strtotime($b_posts[0]->post_date);
    }

    return strcmp($b_cmp, $a_cmp); 
}
```

In order to use that function, next to the following line:

```
$subcats = get_categories('child_of=' . $catid.'&number=2');
```

add the following line:

```
usort($subcats, 'sort_categories_by_post_date');
```

Please, note that this will sort only the 2 pulled categories. So you might want to pull all post categories (which means to remove the `&number=2`), sort them, and then use the following code to get the first 2 of them:

```
$subcats = array_slice($subcats, 0, 2);
```